# How to simulate a bluetooth mouse programmatically

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, hardware, simulation, wireless

we have seen bluetooth/wireless mouses/keyboards which can do the same as wired counterparts. i have an idea of writing an app to simulate the same functionality using a bluetooth device such as a mobile phone because there should be a way that wireless device send the signal via bluetooth to the PC. if anybody know how a wireless mouse/keyboard send signal via bluetooth or wifi to the PC. any resource or source code would be great.

Thanks...

Comment: Unfortunately, you're not going to find a Bluetooth adapter that supports this profile in this manner.

Comment: Mice and keyboards implement the Bluetooth Human Interface Device (HID) profile.

Comment: @TJD can you explain further how can use this interface please ? @ Keshan I am working on the same problem. Have you managed to find a solution ?